# Using the comparison Test to see if a series converges or diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

∑1/(1+(n^3)):

Im trying to use the limit comparison test, but I'm struggling to find the comparing equation.  I would appreciate if someone could either give me advice to finding the comparing equations and/or the equation of the this problem.

Comment: This should remind you of $\sum \frac{1}{n^3}$. There are other choices, but I think this one is most natural. You need to have as background knowledge that for $p\gt 1$, $\sum \frac{1}{n^p}$ converges.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1/(1+n^3)<1/n^3<1/n^2

so 
sigma 1/n^2 =pi^2/6 converge

0<1/(1+n^3)<1/n^3<1/n^2

then sigma 1/(1+n^3) converge

Comment: Why don't you use Latex? :)